# What method of delay can i use to force socket await my response in smtp

Tags: node.js, ssl, smtp

I have an issue with incoming messages, when some service connecting to my smtp server, it's writting data reaaly fast(i mean about 0.5ms delay) and my server doens't support this speed, because it need to generate response and eventually i see something like this:

[image]

When service sends me MAIL FROM and RCPT TO commands, at this time i'm still sending the header. My question is: how can i force the socket wait for my response (net.socket and tls.tlssocket)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not caused by the client but by a broken reply of your server.

In a multiline reply (i.e. in your reply to EHLO) all but the last line should start with the  3-digit response code immediately followed by a dash, i.e. "250-<space>...". Based on the output you have instead a space before the dash ("250<space>-<space>...") and thus this gets interpreted as the final line of the reply.

This means the client will interpret each of these broken lines as a reply to the last command and will continue with the next command. This fails if it gets a response code 250 for the DATA command because 354 is expected.

Comment: Thank a lot Steffen, i've changed my code and it works perfect

Comment: I'm sorry, @steffen-ullrich, may i ask you to check another my issue, it's about Headers Detecting, gmail system tells me that my message does'nt have FROM, but i has.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73748023/our-system-has-detected-that-this-message-is-not-rfc-5322-compliant